# Get Number of Rows from a Select statement

Tags: php, sql, pdo, count, odbc

I have this:

```
$dbh = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=$mdbFilename", $username, $password);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM this_table";

$stmt = $dbh->query($sql);

//num of rows?
```

How do I get the number of rows returned from that SELECT statement?

Thanks all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found a solution, using fetchAll and then using count on this array - which is what MySQL does anyway internally, a bit inefficient but it works for me.

```
$q = $db->query("SELECT ...");
$rows = $q->fetchAll();
$rowCount = count($rows);
```

From another question [Chad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41665/chad-birch) provided this insight:

> It seems as though the only reason
>   this was possible with MySQL is
>   because it internally fetched all the
>   result rows and buffered them, to be
>   able to give you this information. See
>   mysql_unbuffered_query(). If you use
>   that function instead of
>   mysql_query(), the mysql_num_rows()
>   function will not work. If you really
>   need to know the number of rows while
>   using PDO, you can fetch all of the
>   rows from PDO into an array and then
>   use count().

Hope this is useful to someone.

Comment: Hi, do you have a link to the question you mention? Thanks tho

Comment: This is a **BAD** idea. What if your SELECT returns millions of rows?

Answer (score 8):

`SELECT count(*) FROM this_table` is an option...

Regarding rowCount:

PDOStatement::rowCount() returns the number of rows affected by the last DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement executed by the corresponding PDOStatement object.

If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows returned by that statement. **

However, this behaviour is not guaranteed for all databases and should not be relied on for portable applications.

Comment: I don't want to run another query.

Comment: This link may be of some help: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

Answer (score -1):

You can use mysqli_num_rows() function here. It returns number of rows from the sql query.

```
mysqli_num_rows($stmt);
```

Comment: You **cannot** use mysqli_num_rows with PDO

Comment: Sorry, I used the PHP mysql connectivity reference here.